# bash AND-list does not work

Tags: bash, list, function

I have a export function looking like:

```
foo()
{
   ( set -e; false; echo foo is running; )
}
```

On the following command

```
foo && do_other_stuff
```

"foo is running" was printed and do_other_stuff got executed unexpectedly.
As comparison, the command

```
foo; echo $?
```

got executed normally.

My bash version is 4.3.33. So it is a bug?

Comment: No, it is not a bug! Why do you think so?

Comment: Actually the foo function is  foo() { (set -e; make; echo make is okay); } so that I cannot put a false in the end.  foo() { (set -e; make; echo make is okay); return $; } got the same results.

Comment: @bufh: Why should that be so? `set -e` should cause the subshell started by the `()` to exit when `false` returns a failure status; that failure status should be returned by the subshell and hence (as the last command) by `foo`. Why does `foo && do_other_stuff` cause `foo is running` to be printed when, for example, `foo ; do_other_stuff` or `! foo` don't?

Comment: @Mithrandir: My comment above describes why I believe this is a bug - do you disagree? The answer from bufh refers to the man page description of "set -e", but I don't find this convincing as an explanation, because (1) it makes no sense for a function / subshell to behave in that way, and (2) the behaviour is not consistent (see my comments below that answer). If you believe it's still a bug, could you possibly explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understood the second half of your question.

```
foo() { ( set -e; false; echo foo is running; ) }
foo; echo $? # just print 1
foo && echo bar # shows "foo is running" and "bar"
```

From the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a **while** or **until** keyword, part of the test following the **if** or **elif** reserved words, part of any command executed in a **&&** or **││** list except the command following the final **&&** or **││**, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with **!**.

This is indeed difficult to understand :^)

Since `foo` is followed by a `&&`, I understand the shell will not exit immediately.

When doing:

```
foo() { ( set -e; false; echo foo is running; ); false; }

foo && echo bar # will only print "foo is running"
```

Because the "set -e" is not executed.

I suppose you want to do:

```
foo() {
    ( # facultative
        return 1; # abort here with a non-zero status
        echo foo is running
    ) # ...
}
foo && echo bar; echo $? # print "1"
```

Comment: But `! foo` doesn't print `foo is running`, whereas that part of the man page says it has the same effect on `-e` (and in general it does - neither `! true` nor `! false` cause the shell to exit).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your last comment, for me (bash 3.2 and 4.2) `if foo; then echo bar;fi` act the same than `foo && echo bar`.

Comment: That section of the man page says that bash won't exit if the failing command is: (1) the condition of `while`, `until`, `if`, `elif`; or (2) the (non-final) condition in a `&&` or `||` test; or (3) anything in a pipeline except the last command; or (4) a command prefixed by `!`. If the `foo` from the question is used in (1) or (2) it doesn't print `foo is running`. But if you use it in (3) or (4) it *does* print it. So I'm not sure this is a full explanation of what's going on (and to me at the moment it's seeming like a bug!).

Comment: Sorry, I got that the wrong way round - in (1) and (2) it *does* print the message; in (3) and (4) it *doesn't*.